# Spam Filtering used by service providers(User customization)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, spam, spam-prevention, text-classification

I am learning about the spam filtering techniques implemented by various email service providers. Precisely this is treated as a classification problem and various techniques such as Bayesian, SVM(Support Vector Machines) , KNN etc are used to created a model for classification.

I understood everything till these methodologies. But i got a little confused when i have seen the User Customization For spam filtering in Gmail(we can choose any mail to be spam or non-spam). **How exactly they implement this option. Will they create a separate classification model for each user or is there any other option/technique to do this.**

I have tried to search it on web but didn't got satisfactory results.

Comment: Feature hashing is the key, there was a paper about that.

Answer (score 0):

Different people has different preference thus we indeed need separate classification model for each user. For the sake of efficience, we divide users to several groups which have different models. 
   The most challenging thing is data collecting. The data is often incomplete, error prone and not accessible